# Is there a way to see all my edits on one page with their approval stats?

Tags: support, edits

I've made 15 approved edits so far and would like to see some stats (were there edits which are disapproved by one reviewer? I guess I should know about such cases to improve what I do. Where there any disapproved edits? How much time usually elapses between an edit and 3 reviews?)

There's an interface (https://stackoverflow.com/users/some_sort_of_id/username?tab=activity&sort=revisions) that allows to see all my edits (including those made to my own posts), but the approval status is painfully far from it (have to go to the post page, click "edited .. ago" link, click "edit approved" link there - and that's for one edit), which is obviously not what I want.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/3995261/yakovl?tab=activity&sort=suggestions ?

Comment: Also note that "revisions" only shows _approved_ suggested edits, or the ones that get applied. David's link will get you exactly what you want, and clicking the status will take you to view the review if you want to see that. If you want to see all the review pages on one page, that's a nope.

Comment: @DavidPostill this is much more helpful, although it would be nicer to have "n times approved, m times rejected" stats (and may be sliders for more details like rejection reasons) on the same page instead of having to check out each suggestion on a separate page.